# How to repeat an animation in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, repeat

I am using the example from:
https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-animation/

How can I play the animation repeatedly? 
So once the play button is clicked it will continue playing repeatedly?
Another option is to have the animation play non stop once the animation is loaded.

Comment: The documentation is truly sparse, I can't even find docs on Plotly.animate() - just examples.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be found [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#animating-many-frames-quickly). The idea is that instead of passing all frames beforehand you create them on the fly using the `update` function.
The plot is created with `Plotly.animate()`.

You can also change this example to fit your case. Iterate through your list of data points. Once you reach the end of your array, set the counter to 0 to start at the beginning.

This example uses `redraw: false`, which can be used to update the plot at high frame rates.

```
var n = 100;
var x = [], y = [], z = [];
var dt = 0.015;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  x[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  y[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  z[i] = 30 + Math.random() * 10;
}

Plotly.plot('graph', [{
  x: x,
  y: z,
  mode: 'markers'
}], {
  xaxis: {range: [-40, 40]},
  yaxis: {range: [0, 60]}
})

function compute () {
  var s = 10, b = 8/3, r = 28;
  var dx, dy, dz;
  var xh, yh, zh;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dx = s * (y[i] - x[i]);
    dy = x[i] * (r - z[i]) - y[i];
    dz = x[i] * y[i] - b * z[i];

    xh = x[i] + dx * dt * 0.5;
    yh = y[i] + dy * dt * 0.5;
    zh = z[i] + dz * dt * 0.5;

    dx = s * (yh - xh);
    dy = xh * (r - zh) - yh;
    dz = xh * yh - b * zh;

    x[i] += dx * dt;
    y[i] += dy * dt;
    z[i] += dz * dt;
  }
}

function update () {
  compute();

  Plotly.animate('graph', {
    data: [{x: x, y: z}]
  }, {
    transition: {
      duration: 0
    },
    frame: {
      duration: 0,
      redraw: false
    }
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```